# Why do I get property of undefined error?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

it happens when I add in the line of code

```
let ServicePlugin = new ServicePlugin();
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong? Below is the full code.

```
'use strict';

class ServicePlugin {
  constructor(api) {
    this._api = api;

    this._api.on('ready', () => this._apiReady());
    this._api.on('saveSuccess', () => this._apiSuccess());
  }

  _apiReady() {
    console.log('Plugin Ready')
  }

  _apiSuccess() {
    console.log('Plugin Success');
  }

}

let ServicePlugin = new ServicePlugin();
ServicePlugin._apiReady();

module.exports = ServicePlugin;
```

Comment: `new AnnServicePlugin();` what have you passed to constructor?  -- `undefined`. So, console is not lying to you. In simple words `this._learnosity = undefined;` and `on()` is not defined on `undefined`.

Comment: What is `learnosity`? Where is it ever defined?

Comment: The problem is that the constructor is called without arguments. As a result `learnosity` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must provide the `learnosity` parameter (whatever that is) when you instantiate your class. `AnnServicePlugin` expects it:

```
let annServicePlugin = new AnnServicePlugin(learnosity);
```

Of course, the `learnosity` object must have the expected `on` method.